# How do I get StructureMap to resolve a specific instance?

Tags: c#, structuremap

In the following code, I would simply like StructureMap (v2.6.4.1) map all requests for `IMyService` to a specific `myService` instance.  Here's the code that's failing:

```
IMyService myService = ...;

ObjectFactory.Configure(r =>
{
    r.For<IMyService>().Use(myService)
});

IMyService resolvedInstance = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMyService>();
```

The call to `Configure` fails with the error:

```
Type Instance 'dfa538d3-593d-4ca9-9c39-4b3538023483' (Object:  
MyServices.IMyService) cannot be plugged into type MyServices.IMyService, 
MyServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

I've tried using `.Singleton()`, `.TheDefault.IsThis`, and `ObjectFactory.Inject`, among other things, all with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

In my case "myService" is assigned an instance returned from `System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<IMyService>.CreateChannel()`, which, at runtime, the debugger shows that it is of type `System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy`.

I found that it works if I use `Use(() => myService)`.  I'd still like to know why it fails in this particular case.

Comment: The error seems to say you that you are wiring a `IMyService` object to a `IMyService` interface. Can you check if defining the variable as, for example, `MyService` class type the error still reproduces?

Comment: In this case I'm trying to wire it to a proxy class, so there is no concrete class to deal with.

Comment: But... The proxy class must implement `IMyService`, isn't it? I'm sure I am missing something, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You left out a key detail: what exactly are you storing in the myService variable? From the error message, it looks like there is a type mismatch.

Comment: In my case it's an instance returned from `System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<IMyService>.CreateChannel()`, which, at runtime, the debugger shows that it is of type `System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy`.